# 'str' object has no attribute 'comparisons'

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

actually I get this error many times I do not know from where it comes.!
my function is to count the the total comparisons in bst,
her is my code

```
def total(bst):
     s = Stack()
        total = 0
        s.push(bst._root)
        while not s.is_empty():
            x = s.pop()
            nu = x._value
            total = total + nu.comparisons
            if x._right:
                s.push(x._right)
            if node._left:
                s.push(x._left)

        return total
```

here is the error

```
total = total + i.comparisons
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'comparisons'
```

here is the claas of letter:

```
class Letter:

    def __init__(self, letter):

        assert letter.isalpha() and letter.isupper(), "Invalid letter"

        self.letter = letter
        self.count = 0
        self.comparisons = 0
        return

    def __str__(self):

        return "{}: {}, {}".format(self.letter, self.count, self.comparisons)

    def __eq__(self, rs):

        self.count += 1
        self.comparisons += 1
        result = self.letter == rs.letter
        return result

    def __lt__(self, rs):

        self.comparisons += 1
        result = self.letter < rs.letter
        return result

    def __le__(self, rs):

        self.comparisons += 1
        result = self.letter <= rs.letter
        return result
```

can any one explain it to me,thanks for any healp.

Comment: You're define self.comparisons as a value for class Letter. `num` is a string value, so in order to use it, you have to define a letter object to use comparisons on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `i` (or `num`) is a `str`, which does not have `comparisons` attribute. Your `Letter` objects however do. Maybe cast it into a `Letter` and then try using `comparisons` like so: `Letter(i).comparisons`.

EDIT:

The reason as to why comparisons are always empty is because you never compare that variable to something else (which is where the comparisons get incremented, see your `__eq__` in `Letter`). They will only start changing if you say something like `i=Letter(i)`, then compare that `i` to something like `i == 1`. Only then will your comparisons get incremented.